# trying to add a stats object to a DoublyLinkedList

Tags: c++, object, constructor, append

Im trying to add a Stats object which would be a player with first, last name ,level and experience.  I have that set up in a Stats.h.  But my problem is in the main i cannot figure out how to add the stats player to the list.  Here is what i am trying to do:

```
Stats stats;
DoublyLinkedList<Stats> list;
DoublyLinkedListIterator<Stats> itr = list.getIterator();


int main ()
{
    Stats s1 = ("John","Campbell",0,0);//This causes error.
    //No suitable conversion between int and string.

    list.Append(s1);
    list.Append(144);
    list.Append(1);
    list.Append(1111);
    list.Prepend(1000);
```

I really cant figure out if i am attempting it correctly or if i am off course completely. Any help will be greatly appreiacted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stats s1 = ("John","Campbell",0,0);//This causes error.
```

You should do this

```
Stats s1("John","Campbell",0,0);
```

Comment: Correct.  Feel like such a noob haha

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant:

```
Stats s1("John","Campbell",0,0);
```

That's assuming that `Stats` has a constructor that accepts those four parameters.

If `Stats` is a POD `struct` containing those four datatypes, this will work:

```
Stats s1 = {"John","Campbell",0,0};
```

And if you're using C++11, either case would work with:

```
Stats s1 {"John","Campbell",0,0};
```